# Read data from xml / csv file in Android application

Tags: android, xml, csv

Is it possible to read data from xml / csv file and display in android application? Any pointers would be extremely helpful.

Comment: When you searched on `android (xml OR csv) parser` on a major search engine, what did you learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first put your xml file in raw folder

then try this(Xml pull Parser)

```
String temp1 = "" ,string 1;

    final InputStream object = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);
    final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(object);

           try {                    
                XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();  

                parser.setInput(isr);           
                int eventType = parser.getEventType();

                while (true)
                {
                if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)  
                    {
                    break;
                    }   
               else
                    temp1 = parser.getName();                       
                    {
                    switch(eventType)                           

                        {       case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:                       

                                break;                      

                                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                              parser.getName());    

                                    if(temp1.equalsIgnoreCase("Your Conditions")) {
                                        string 1 = parser.nextText();    
                                    //save the parsed message to string                     
                                    }   


                                    break;                                                                      

                                case  XmlPullParser.END_TAG:                 
                                break;


                        case  XmlPullParser.TEXT:

                             break;                  
                        }     

                        eventType = parser.next();              

                        }   
               }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Xml pull parser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html). Good documentation can be found on the developer site of android.

Comment: Thanks for the response Aashish. How about a csv file?

Comment: You can write custom parser for csv.